# How to make nerdcommenter treat .ctp files as .html - VIM

Tags: vim

I use [nerdcommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) to comment code.

I comment by `<leader>cc`. It does work great when I do it with **.html** file types. It surrounds code with **<--** code **-->**

But with **.ctp** files I have to change filetype to html first by `:set filetype=html`, and it starts working as expected, but my syntax highlight changes too.

Is there a way to make **nerdcommenter** treat **.ctp** files as **.html**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ryuichiro it was solved. [Here is the full post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561010/why-filetype-works-and-bufread-bufnewfile-doesnt-vim?answertab=active#tab-top).

We just have to use alternative commenting like:

```
let g:NERDCustomDelimiters = {
     \ 'php': { 'left': '//', 'leftAlt': '<!--', 'rightAlt': '-->' }
     \ }
```

And, to change to alternative commenting style, use `<Leader>ca`

[Again, here is the full post why and how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561010/why-filetype-works-and-bufread-bufnewfile-doesnt-vim?answertab=active#tab-top).

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your `.vimrc`

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.ctp set filetype=html
```

By this line, you make vim assign the filetype by the file extension automatically.

Comment: (+1) Thank you very much for your help. Maybe, there is a way to change it only for nerdtcommente, because I don't want to change syntax  highlight?)

Answer (score 1):

Nerdcommenter uses the `'commentstring'` setting to determine which sort of comment to use.  `:h 'commentstring'` gives the following:

```
                    *'commentstring'* *'cms'* *E537*
'commentstring' 'cms'   string  (default "/*%s*/")
            local to buffer
            {not in Vi}
            {not available when compiled without the |+folding|
            feature}
    A template for a comment.  The "%s" in the value is replaced with the 
comment text.
```

You could use `:setlocal cms` to change the comment string for the active buffer, or even use an autocommand to `:setlocal` for you whenever you open the appropriate file type.

Edit:  I suppose I should say that I haven't actually tried this with nerdcommenter in particular, but if it uses `'commentstring'` like the documentation says, this should work.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I tried `set commentstring=\"%s
set commentstring?` and I'm getting `commentstring="%s` But it still comments in the same way.