# Why FileType works and BufRead,BufNewFile doesn't - VIM?

Tags: vim

When I put `autocmd` with `FileType` into my `.vimrc` it does work.

```
autocmd FileType ctp setlocal commentstring=#test\ %s
```

When I call `<leader>cc` [|NERDComComment|](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) it does work and puts `#test` as a comment. But I have to change filetype first by `set ft=ctp`, but it messes my syntax highlight, that's why I want to be able to set it by file extension.

But when I try to use `BufRead,BufNewFile` it doesn't  work

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.ctp setlocal commentstring=#test\ %s
```

How can I set `setlocal commentsting` by file extension and not by type.

Comment: @work.bin Thank you for your comment, I tried `BufEnter` - getting the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ctp` belongs to php filetype group. So if you wish to have [alternative commenting style](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter/blob/master/doc/NERD_commenter.txt#L409)

```
let g:NERDCustomDelimiters = {
   \ 'php': { 'left': '//', 'leftAlt': '#test ' }
   \ }
```

in your `.vimrc`. To change to alternative commenting style, use `<Leader>ca`.

Problem with other methods is that the NERD Commenter [uses a filetype and its own set of rules to set its commenting style.](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter/blob/master/plugin/NERD_commenter.vim#L458) [If it is not found, then it uses `&cms` option.](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter/blob/master/plugin/NERD_commenter.vim#L466)

Comment: Sorry, one more question ^^ Can it be used only for .ctp files? Like `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.ctp let g:NERDCustomDelimiters = { 'php': { 'left': '//', 'leftAlt': '<!--', 'rightAlt': '-->' } }`

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems impossible to use that `autocmd` for `g:NERDCustomDelimiters` is not added to `g:NERDDelimiterMap` in that phase anymore. Maybe it is possible to `let b:NERDCommenterDelims = {'left': '//', 'leftAlt': '<--', 'right': '', 'rightAlt': '-->'}` directly only for `*.ctp` but I do not know the right trigger event to use. For example, `au CursorMoved *.ctp let b:NERDCommenterDelims = {'left': '//', 'leftAlt': '<--', 'right': '', 'rightAlt': '-->'}` works, but it is really not nice :-)

Comment: Thank you for your awesome help. I learn a lot from you. Thank you.